# How can I identify this QFN IC marked GX?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, lvds

I'm trying to identify what this part could be based on the top marking, GX, but I've been totally unable to find it online. I'm pretty sure the packaging is QFN, it has 16 pins, and I know it has something to do with LVDS. It appears to have two LVDS inputs and either two LVDS outputs or one and a pair of single ended outputs that is uses to output to the microprocessor. The rest appear to be single ended, with one lead that goes into some kind of op-amp circuit which outputs into another lead on it.

I suppose what I'm looking for is any advice how I can find what this part is or how I can learn more about what it could be based on its pins. There are also some dashes on the case that I'm not sure the meaning of. There are the four dashes on the left side of the marking and another two on the right.

[image: This is a picture I took with a microscope]

Comment: I almost want to say those four dashes could be a manufacturer logo, but I don't recognise it if it is one.

Comment: @Hearth maybe Black Flag is an IC vendor now?

Comment: @Hearth Yeah I was thinking it might be too but I couldn't find any that matched it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a [FSA2567UMX](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fsa2567-d.pdf)  Low-Power, Dual SIM Card Analog Switch in an  Ultrathin Molded Leadless Package (UMLP) 1.8 x 2.6 mm package.

Comment: Wow! That looks like it very well could be the part. The Vcc, GND, and NC line up at least. Could I ask what you did to find that schematic?